# Is there a way to retrieve data of a Google Form ITSELF (not spreadsheet) using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-forms

I would like to build a node.js server and use it to retrieve data of a Google Form, like: title, type, options of questions on that form.

e.g.

If I have a Google Form:
http://goo.gl/forms/DSNFS0cfgw

I would like to do somthing like:

```
var form = getFormData();

// returns 
// [
//   {title: "Name", type: "text", options:[]},
//   {title: "Favorite Season", type: "select", options:["spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter"]},
//   {title: "Favorite Fruit", type: "radio", options:["apple", "banana"]}
// ]
```

Is there a way to do this by using Javascript or any node module?

Comment: what do you mean by the FORM-ITSELF???

Comment: @TomerW The way I understood it, he wants to parse the form to grab the titles, options, etc.

Comment: do you mean the form submitting directly to your server? 
do you mean being notified when the form submits?
elseway, what's wrong with the spreadsheet approach ?

Comment: @Second Rikudo Thank you, Second Rikudo, that is what i meant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a lot of options aside from whipping up **[cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)** and parsing the HTML source.

Cheerio looks and feels a lot like jQuery, so if you're familiar with that, you shouldn't have a lot of problems.